# ssh in heroku receive "uploading ssh public key failed"

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When i try to connect in the first time to my heroku app, i see the following message :

> "found existing public key :c:/users/idan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub uploading
>   ssh public key c:/users/idan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... failed  !
>   application error "

that despite the fact that when I open the path : `c:/users/idan/.ssh`
i find the file `id_rsa` in this folder
moreover, when i type `"heroku keys"`
I receive the message that "`no keys founds`"

how can i fix it?

thanks 
idan

Answer (score 4):

Add your key to SSH:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then add that key file to Heroku's list of SSH keys associated to your account.

https://dashboard.heroku.com/account