# Heroku - Uploading SSH public key failed

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I just got a new computer and I tried to download the code from heroku. It said I had no keys, so I did heroku keys:clear to add new ones.

Then :

```
heroku keys
You have no keys.

c:\Node\app>heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: C:/Users/Zela/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/Zela/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... failed
 !      Application error
```

I found nothing about this anywhere else...

*Note : i firstly named my computer after my name,  Léo, which got my paths issues due to the "é" letter on my Windows8, so I added a second account with admin privileges after that. Didn't re install heroku toolbelt &git thought still commands were still working.*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14900586/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15291232/6309 don't help?

Comment: the first link seems promising, i'll try to add it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay problem solved, all I had to do was to copy/paste exactly what I add in :

```
C:/Users/<Other CPU Username>/.ssh
```

which means the 3 files  id_rsa,  id_rsa.pub  and  known_hosts